# 'Request-Id' & 'Request-Context' not getting added

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights

I am creating a angular app and trying to add appinsights to the angular app. The config is set as follows:

```
private config: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IConfig = {
    instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
    disableCorrelationHeaders: false,
    enableDebug : true,
    verboseLogging : true
}
```

and app insights is initialized as follows in a angular service.

```
if (!AppInsights.config) {
  AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(this.config);
}
```

But I am not seeing dependency calls having the following headers
    'Request-Id'
    'Request-Context'

Was anyone successful in getting this to work?

Comment: I have tested app insights on my side, I didn't see these two headers. And in this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies),we also can not see Request-Id and Request-Context header. So what did you mean? Are they customs header in your code?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#config Kindly look at this. These are not custom headers. But app insight headers.

Comment: In this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-correlation), it mentioned the correlation headers like Request-Id and Request-Context, you could refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Also try setting `enableCorsCorrelation: true`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#configuration